# Is it safe to always access odd-sized datastructures in multiples of 4 bytes?

Tags: delphi, memory-alignment

If `SizeOf(datastructure)` is not a multiple of 4. It can be awkward to access the remaining few bytes.
I want to optimize this by reading the remaining 1,2 or 3 bytes in a 4 byte variable and then masking off the bytes I don't need.

This should not give exceptions, because blocks should be allocated in dword (or bigger) aligned chunks.

Let me give an example:

```
function MurmurHash3(data: PInteger; size: integer; seed: Cardinal): Cardinal;
const
  ....
{$ifdef purepascal}
var
  i: integer;
  k,hash: cardinal;
  remaining: cardinal;
begin
  hash:= seed;
  for i:= 0 to (size shr 2)-1 do begin
    ... do murmur stuff
  end; {for i}
  remaining:= data[size shr 2];  //access the remaining 1,2,3 bytes
  //mask off the bytes we don't need.
  remaining:= remaining and ($ffffffff shr ((size and $3)*8));
  ....
```

Is this safe or will this land me in trouble?

Comment: What version of Delphi is this?

Comment: @DavidDubois, XE7, but that the code should run in even in D2.

Comment: What difference does it make, @David?

Answer (score 4):

This is safe if and only if it is valid to read beyond the end of the data to a multiple of 4. If the byte array is held in an integer array then you are fine. If it is actually held in a byte array then you could be reading off the end of the buffer.

What I mean by this is that although your function accepts `PInteger`, that might have been done for sake of convenience when addressing the array. If the caller of the function has cast `PByte` to `PInteger` at the call site, then it is at least plausible that you could be reading off the end of the array and potentially encounter a runtime memory fault.

You mention that a desire to optimise is driving this. I'm not sure that the final step of a hash calculation will need optimising. The loop is where you incur the cost. I doubt you'd suffer very much by using `Move` to perform a copy of the straggling bytes into an integer variable. If you really want to optimise, break 3 into 2 then 1, and then 2 and 1 can be handled by register access.

Comment: As long as the start of the structure is aligned, no aligned over-read of 1,2 or 3 bytes should ever trigger a AV, however if you're starting the hash in the middle of a packed record, you can start hashing on a unaligned address and then the read can pass beyond the bounds, triggering a AV.

Comment: I settled on the move into an integer.

Comment: I'd be astounded if it mattered either way. The advantage of doing 3 as 2 plus 1 is that you can read direct into a register. But then you need to do two ops. So who knows which is faster. But in any case, the loop will be where the time is spent I bet.

Comment: @Johan: It is never a good idea to access past the boundaries of an array, especially if that means that random filler bytes are taken into consideration, possibly giving different hash results for actually identical valid data. It may also go berserk on a new platform.

Comment: @Rudy He's masking them out. The issue is whether or not they random filler bytes can be read before being masked.

Comment: Sorry, must have been the heat. But still, I am not so sure if you can actually really always access beyond an array, masking or not. I would not count on it.

Comment: I just wanted to express agreement and support your arguments, no more.